# Presto group by distinct values in hive array

Tags: sql, hive, presto

In hive you can group on distinct values in an Hive array like this:

```
SELECT i, count(distinct cookieID) as unique_visitor, count(*) as impressions FROM table LATERAL VIEW explode(interests) interestTable AS i GROUP BY i;
```

How can you achieve the same in Presto?

Doesn't have to be with a group by, just the same result (and hopefully faster) than in Hive is fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet, but it is on the roadmap.

Comment: Guess I will wait for that feature then :)